# How to rectify the walls of buildings in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, sql

I need an operations in PostGIS to eliminate intermediate vertexes in a polygon to rectify the walls of a building.

I was revising http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiExamplesSpikeRemover but it only works to eliminate spikes.

example:

[image: example]

Answer (score 7):

Applying a douglas-peucker filter with a small parameter value (like one meter) should remove these points. See [ST_Simplify](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Simplify.html).